# Order of molecular mass of solvent; given boiling point

Tags: solutions, solvents, colligative-properties

> Given three solvents X, Y, Z. Order of boiling point of pure solvent X < Y < Z and same order of molal elevation constant ($K_\mathrm{b}$). Find the order of molecular mass.

So I got this question in my tuition test and the solution is unclear. This question is troubling me a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see how this question is troubling.

It don't think there is a solution.

$K_b = \frac{RT_b^2M_w}{1000\Delta H_v}$

Where $T_b$ is boiling point, $\Delta H_v$ is the molar heat of vaporization, and $M_w$ is molecular weight of the solvent.

(see [Colligative Properties by W. R. Salzman](http://www.chem.arizona.edu/~salzmanr/480a/480ants/colprop/colprop.html))

So you can see that knowing $K_b$ and $T_b$ is insufficient to find $M_w$, knowledge of $\Delta H_v$ is also required.

Experimentally, from [Table of cryoscopic and ebullioscopic constants](http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_eduen/qui/tcriosebu.pdf) you can also see there is no solution.